# How to connect a RDP machine to a VPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, rdp

When I try to connect my RDP machine to a VPN(PPTP), I get disconnected from my RDP.

My understanding so far is that all the traffic, including the RDP traffic, is being routed to a different interface (the VPN interface), so the route of the RDP traffic has changed, so I get disconnected.

My research has lead me to the concept of split tunneling, which basically allows you to route traffic for specific subnets to a different gateway (I'm not sure if my terminologies are correct), while possible, I still cant figure out how to differentiate the RDP traffic to not be tunneled to the VPN interface.

Is there anyway to solve this? Is there anyway I could make sure that RDP traffic still stays on the normal route, while all other traffic goes through the VPN? Or maybe, is there a way I could connect to the RDP  even if it's traffic is now routed to the VPN?

Comment: Traffic of interest is sent through the tunnel and others aren’t. By interesting traffic, I mean all traffic actually destined to machines on the other end of the vpn tunnel. You should be able to identify those subnets easily enough. That is called split-tunneling.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I know about split tunneling, but I dont exactly know how to differentiate traffic from RDP using IP Address alone, and it isn't seem possible to split tunnel by port.

Comment: you do know what IP addresses and subnet ranges exist on the other side of the VPN correct? Those are the destinations that go through the VPN. Everything else does not. That’s a split-tunnel. Your mistake is that you want to try to continue to send everything through the tunnel except for RDP traffic. At least that’s what it seems. That’s not how it works. Split-tunneling is based on route selection, and routes are based on subnet, and specific routes will go through the tunnel (I.e subnets on the other side of the VPN) and the default route (everything else) will not go through the VPN.

Comment: Need more informations.
1. From where you connect to your RDP machine? LAN or internet?
2. What is your VPN’s purpose? for private network? or proxy internet connection?
3. And if possible, copy and paste your route tables with and without VPN.